# Three paritions appears in my pendrive ntfs, ext4 and unallocated (write protected)

Tags: gparted, ntfs, ext4, udisks

I have hp pen-drive with the model v232w. First I created the bootable image for Ubuntu which created ext4 partition and some unallocated space. Then I tried to create bootable image of the windows on the same pen-drive which created three partition named as ntfs, ext4 and write protected unallocated space.

Please see the screenshot below

[image]

## Solutions I tried

1.) I tried with diskpart in windows cmd but no results
2.) I tried with gparted in linux
3.) I tried with some software such as **AOMEI Partition Assistant

Professional Edition, EaseUS Partition Master Free** but no use

I think there should be some software which should come for all companies such as hp, sandisk which can format the pen-drive irrespective of any partition in the pen-drive. (**hp pen drive flash software**)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? What do you want to do now with the pendrive? Format it, in that case how? Or use it for some special purpose, for example to make an installer drive? Maybe you can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035), and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Comment: I was using ubuntu 20.04 and using the software startup disk creator to make ubuntu iso bootable. It was made and then decided to make windows bootable for some reasons using unetbootin but cancelled the process accidentally. This  created three partition as discussed above.

Comment: Thanks :-) The Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator is reliable, so I think there is another problem. Please answer also to the other questions. It will help me and others to help you . (Otherwise we can only guess.) You may also be able to help yourself after reading the web page at the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) in my first comment. For example, **mkusb** will often fix the problem if you wipe the first mibibyte or use it to create a standard USB drive (with the FAT32 file system.)

Comment: Hi thanks. I tried with mkusb but when i again plugin i can see three partitions in the pendrive as before i.e one for windows, another for ubuntu and third which is unallocated and write protected. Can you suggest something to flash the drive.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm afraid that the pendrive is gridlocked, which means that can appear to receive write commands, but nothing is happening. The drive itself is read-only, a first phase of failure. It might still be possible to read whatever might be worth saving from the drive, but that is all you can do with it. - However, you can check in another computer, with another operating system, in another USB port and when all other USB devices are disconnected etc, because the problem might also be caused by confusion.